# How to calculate the daylight saving time given a latitude and longitude

Tags: python, javascript, c#, java, php

I've been using an algorithm (https://gist.github.com/assaflavi/fc8cf83c167558ebf3ab159b5c5b0df2) to calculate sunrise and sunset times given a latitude and longitude and it works fine but this calculation doesn't have in count the daylight saving times.

Is there a way to calculate this daylight saving times to add them into the sunrise and sunset time?

Comment: Going to need a whole lot more information. What are you trying to do, what have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: And why not use a library? It seems to be re-inventing a pretty big wheel if not.

Comment: Many countries/areas do not observe it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country

Comment: Please add what have you tried/research?